# Trouble training a Tensorflow MLP to classify inputs -1, 0, or 1

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, machine-learning, neural-network

I'm trying to create a multilayer perceptron to classify sentiment based on some indicators. The sentiment can be -1 (bad), 0 (neutral), or 1 (good). All the classifier examples I can find are one-hot, so I think I'm doing something wrong in the way I adapted this to work on continuous features.

```
# Data Prep
np.random.shuffle(raw_data)
X_vals = raw_data[:-200,0:4]
Y_vals = [(x,) for x in raw_data[:-200,4]]
X_test = raw_data[-200:,0:4]
Y_test = [(x,) for x in raw_data[-200:,4]]

# Parameters
learning_rate = 0.001
training_epochs = 10
batch_size = 200
display_step = 1

# Network Parameters
n_hidden_1 = 16 # 1st layer number of neurons
n_hidden_2 = 16 # 2nd layer number of neurons
n_input = 4
n_classes = 1

# tf Graph input
X = tf.placeholder("float", [None, n_input])
Y = tf.placeholder("float", [None, n_classes])

# Store layers weight & bias
weights = {
    'h1': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_input, n_hidden_1])),
    'h2': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_hidden_1, n_hidden_2])),
    'out': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_hidden_2, n_classes]))
}
biases = {
    'b1': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_hidden_1])),
    'b2': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_hidden_2])),
    'out': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_classes]))
}


# Create model
def multilayer_perceptron(x):
    # Hidden fully connected layer with 256 neurons
    layer_1 = tf.nn.tanh(tf.add(tf.matmul(x, weights['h1']), biases['b1']))
    # Hidden fully connected layer with 256 neurons
    layer_2 = tf.nn.tanh(tf.add(tf.matmul(layer_1, weights['h2']), biases['b2']))
    # Output fully connected layer with a neuron for each class
    out_layer = tf.matmul(layer_2, weights['out']) + biases['out']
    return out_layer

# Construct model
logits = multilayer_perceptron(X)

# Define loss and optimizer
loss_op = tf.losses.mean_squared_error(labels=Y,
                                        predictions=tf.nn.softmax(logits))
optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=learning_rate)
train_op = optimizer.minimize(loss_op)

# Initializing the variables
init = tf.global_variables_initializer()

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init)

    # Training cycle
    for epoch in range(training_epochs):
        avg_cost = 0.
        total_batch = int(raw_data.shape[0]/batch_size)
        # Loop over all batches
        for i in range(total_batch):
            batch_x = X_vals[epoch*batch_size:(epoch+1)*batch_size]
            batch_y = Y_vals[epoch*batch_size:(epoch+1)*batch_size]
            # Run optimization op (backprop) and cost op (to get loss value)
            _, c = sess.run([train_op, loss_op], feed_dict={X: batch_x,
                                                            Y: batch_y})
            print("Optimization Finished!")

# Test model
pred = tf.nn.softmax(logits)  # Apply softmax to logits
correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.round(pred), Y)
# Calculate accuracy
accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, "float"))
print("Accuracy:", accuracy.eval({X: X_test, Y: Y_test}))
```

So what I expect all of that should do is to create a tanh perceptron with 2 hidden layers of 16 neurons each and a softmax output layer, train it on all but 200 of my data points, then test it on the last 200. It should spit out values between -1 and 1, which I then round to evaluate against the correct labels of -1, 0, or 1.

I think I must be doing something wrong, because it comes out no better than random chance, even with 30% Pearson correlation between the inputs and the output. This was supposed to be really simple.

Comment: [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  Please supply representative input data: simply hard-code the value of `raw_data` at the top of your program.  Also remember to include other support needed to make your program run as posted.

Comment: You should be able to generate random data with ~30% correlation between input features and outputs and reproduce this. I'll see what I can do about providing sample data that I'm allowed to share.

Comment: Why `n_classes=1`?? Also, since you have a classification problem, you shouldn't use mean squared error, which is for regression ones...

Comment: I only need one output neuron; I want the value there to range from -1 to 1, since my three categories are -1, 0, and 1. I believe mean squared error is appropriate here since it's behaving more like a fitting problem.

Comment: Generating "random data with ~30% correlation between input features and outputs and reproduce this" should be *your* job, not of potential respondents...!

Comment: You ain't gonna solve this with one output neuron & softmax activation...

Comment: I fixed the softmax activation thanks to Nate M's reply. I'm still trying to figure out what else is causing the model to perform poorly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am noticing two things wrong with your model. First of all, a softmax layer limits all of the data to the range [0,1], so you will never get a value of -1 like you want. The data should most definitely be one-hot encoded like you said, because even if your model could spit out a -1, it would still be very biased and not very accurate at test time. So I would change `n_classes` to 3, and make index 0 bad, index 1 neutral, and index 2 good. Your labels should be the 3-vectors where the vector at the correct class index is 1, and 0 elsewhere. This represents a probability distribution over each class label that you want your model to learn.

Finally, you are using the mean squared error (MSE). This is a good error metric for Euclidean embeddings (for example if you wanted to learn the location of a bounding box like YOLO does), but it will not work well for probability distribution embeddings like you want, since it measures the Euclidean distance between the labels and the network output. What you want is `tf.losses.softmax_cross_entropy`. This first sends the data through a softmax, then computes the cross entropy (KL divergence between two **probability distributions**).

So you should change

`loss_op = tf.losses.mean_squared_error(labels=Y,predictions=tf.nn.softmax(logits))`

to

`loss_op = tf.losses.softmax_cross_entropy(onehot_labels=Y,logits=logits)`

making sure to still use softmax during testing.

Finally, you are using a 1 to 1 train/test split. Typically people will use something like 3 to 1 or 3 to 2 so that you have more training data than testing data, which typically leads to better results.

Comment: Thank you for the correction on the softmax!! I've changed that to a tanh, but I'm afraid it's not performing any better. I'm reluctant to switch to one-hot, since what I'm doing feels more like predicting a continuous quantity than classifying something. (Also, I'm using a 10:1 train/test split!)

Comment: I would strongly suggest one-hot encoding the labels as suggested and using the cross entropy loss. You have a class prediction problem here, not a regression one. At least try it before you knock it. Especially since you are not having any luck so far.

Comment: Perhaps I should look at this as a regression problem, not a classification one? The long-term goal is to get a continuous metric for sentiment, between -1 and 1. How might I change my approach if that were the case?

Comment: Ah I see. Well if you want that, you can one-hot encode it, then take the centroid of the logits output of the network to get a value in [-1,1] that will probably be more accurate.

Comment: After switching to one-hot and three categories, I'm still roughly on-par with random chance. Any ideas?